# Why do Xbox controllers have breakaway cables?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

The Xbox and Xbox 360 controllers have extra connections a few inches after the male USB connector.  What is the purpose of this extra connection?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's so that the controller becomes unplugged at the breakaway point when the cable is pulled a little, rather than yanking on your console or controller.  This design mitigates the age old "tripped on the controller cable; yanked my NES off the entertainment center" conundrum.

Comment: Don't forget bent and ruined connectors and wrecked cables.

Comment: Haha.  So why not use a magnet, sort of like apple.  Those are the only connectors I've ever seen actually disconnect when tripped over.

Comment: Really? I thought I was always lucky when I was wading through the mess in my room and tripped over the Xbox cable. You're telling me Microsoft designed that for me? <3

Comment: @KeeganMcCarthy: Well, Apple has [a patent](http://patft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PTXT&s1=7311526.PN.&OS=PN/7311526&RS=PN/7311526) on those connectors.